# Cartesian product from n lists

Tags: java, list, combinations, cartesian-product

I have class `Main` and `Xlist<T>` like below.
I have to do a Cartesian product from `n` lists. In this case from 3.

When I'm doing the product this way:

```java
List<String> list12 = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<String> list22 = Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z");
List<String> list32 = Arrays.asList("1", "2");

cres = XList.computeCombinationsOriginal((Arrays.asList(list12, list22, list32)));
System.out.println(cres);
```

It works great. And I get output:

```
[[a, X, 1], [b, X, 1], [a, Y, 1], [b, Y, 1], [a, Z, 1], [b, Z, 1],
 [a, X, 2], [b, X, 2], [a, Y, 2], [b, Y, 2], [a, Z, 2], [b, Z, 2]]
```

But when I want to do this "automatic" in combine functions, I'm getting

```
[[[a, b], [X, Y, Z], [1, 2]]]
```

Here is all code.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pewne dodatkowe zestawy danych
        Integer[] ints = {100, 200, 300};
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));

        // Sposoby tworzenia
        XList<Integer> list1 = new XList<>(1, 3, 9, 11);

        XList<Integer> list2 = XList.of(5, 6, 9);
        XList<Integer> list3 = new XList(ints);
        XList<Integer> list4 = XList.of(ints);
        XList<Integer> list5 = new XList(set);
        XList<Integer> list6 = XList.of(set);

        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(list3);
        System.out.println(list4);
        System.out.println(list5);
        System.out.println(list6);

        // --- i pomocnicze metody do tworzenia z napisów
        XList<String> slist1 = XList.charsOf("ala ma kota");
        XList<String> slist2 = XList.tokensOf("ala ma kota");
        XList<String> slist3 = XList.tokensOf("A-B-C", "-");

        System.out.println(slist1);
        System.out.println(slist2);
        System.out.println(slist3);

        // Metoda union - suma elementów
        // oczywiście, można podstawiać na List
        List<Integer> m1 = list1.union(list2);
        System.out.println(m1);

        // można wykonywać wszystkie operacje z interfejsu List, np:
        m1.add(11);
        System.out.println(m1);

        XList<Integer> m2 = (XList<Integer>) m1;
        XList<Integer> m3 = m2.union(ints).union(XList.of(4, 4));

        System.out.println(m2); // m2 się nie zmienia
        System.out.println(m3); // wynik jest w m3

        m3 = m3.union(set);
        System.out.println(m3);

        // Widzieliśmy metode union
        // Teraz metoda diff(dowolna kolekcja)
        // wszystko z m3, co nie jest w set
        System.out.println(m3.diff(set));
        //System.out.println("m3" + m3);
        // co jest w set, czego nie ma w m3
        System.out.println(XList.of(set).diff(m3));

        //set = 3,4,5
        //m3 = [1, 3, 9, 11, 5, 6, 9, 11, 100, 200, 300, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5]
        //wynik = 3,4,5 - 0 = 3,4,5

        // Metoda unique -zwraca nową Xlist bez duplikatow
        XList<Integer> uniq = m3.unique(); // lista, nie Set
        System.out.println(uniq);

        // kombinacje (kolejność jest istotna)
        List<String> sa = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        List<String> sb = Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z");
        XList<String> sc = XList.charsOf("12");
        XList toCombine = XList.of(sa, sb, sc);
        System.out.println(toCombine);

        List<List<String>> cres = toCombine.combine();

        List<String> list12 = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        List<String> list22 = Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z");
        List<String> list32 = Arrays.asList("1", "2");

        cres = XList.computeCombinationsOriginal(
                (Arrays.asList(list12, list22, list32)));
        System.out.println(cres);

        /*
        // collect i join
        XList<String> j1 = cres.collect(list -> list.join());
        System.out.println(j1.join(" "));
        XList<String> j2 = cres.collect(list -> list.join("-"));
        System.out.println(j2.join(" "));
        */

        // forEachWithIndex
        XList<Integer> lmod = XList.of(1, 2, 8, 10, 11, 30, 3, 4);
        lmod.forEachWithIndex((e, i) -> lmod.set(i, e * 2));
        System.out.println(lmod);

        lmod.forEachWithIndex((e, i) -> {
            if (i % 2 == 0) lmod.remove(e);
        });
        System.out.println(lmod);

        lmod.forEachWithIndex((e, i) -> {
            if (i % 2 == 0) lmod.remove(i);
        });
        // Pytanie: dlaczego mamy taki efekt?
        System.out.println(lmod);
    }
}
```

And here is the `Xlist` class:

```java
public class XList<T> extends ArrayList {
    private Collection<T> coll;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> listTMP;

    public XList() {
        coll = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public XList(T... arrays) {
        //System.out.println("Pierwszy");
        coll = Arrays.asList(arrays);
    }

    public XList(T[]... arrays) {
        //System.out.println("drugi");
        coll = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T[] arr : arrays)
            for (T t : arr) {
                coll.add(t);
            }
    }

    public XList(Collection<T> col) {
        //System.out.println("Trzeci");
        coll = new ArrayList<>();
        coll.addAll(col);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return coll.toString();
    }

    public static <T> XList<T> of(T... arrays) {
        XList<T> tmp = new XList<>(arrays);
        return tmp;
    }

    public static <T> XList<T> of(T[]... arrays) {
        XList<T> tmp = new XList(arrays);
        return tmp;
    }

    public static <T> XList<T> of(Collection<T> col) {
        //System.out.println("hashset");
        XList<T> tmp = new XList<>(col);
        System.out.println("of");

        return tmp;
    }

    public static <T> XList<T> charsOf(T str) {
        Object tab[] = ((String) str).split("");
        XList<T> tmp = new XList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            tmp.coll.add((T) tab[i]);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public static <T> XList<T> tokensOf(T str) {
        Object tab[] = ((String) str).split("\\s");
        XList<T> tmp = new XList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            tmp.coll.add((T) tab[i]);
        }
        return tmp;
    }


    public static <T> XList<T> tokensOf(T... str) {
        String sep = ((String) str[1]);
        XList<T> tmp = new XList<>();
        for (T t : str) {
            Object tab[] = ((String) t).split(sep);
            for (Object obj : tab)
                tmp.coll.add((T) obj);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public XList<T> union(Collection<T> col) {
        XList<T> returnList = new XList<>();
        if (col instanceof XList) {
            returnList.coll.addAll(this.coll);
            returnList.coll.addAll(((XList) col).coll);
        } else {
            returnList.coll.addAll(this.coll);
            returnList.coll.addAll(col);
        }
        return returnList;
    }

    public XList<T> union(T... arrays) {
        XList<T> returnList = new XList<>();
        returnList.coll.addAll(this.coll);

        for (T t : arrays)
            returnList.coll.add(t);

        return returnList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object obj) {
        coll.add((T) obj);
        return true;
    }

    public Collection<T> getColl() {
        return coll;
    }

    public XList<T> diff(Collection<T> col) {
        Collection<T> cpCol = new ArrayList<>();
        cpCol.addAll(this.coll);
        //Wszystko z this co nie jest w col
        if (col instanceof XList) {
            cpCol.removeAll(((XList) col).getColl());
        } else {
            cpCol.removeAll(col);
        }

        XList<T> returnList = new XList<>();
        returnList.coll = cpCol;
        return returnList;
    }

    public XList<T> unique() {
        XList<T> returnList = new XList<>();
        returnList.coll = this.coll.stream().distinct().collect(toList());
        return returnList;
    }

    public List<List<T>> combine() {
        List<T> listIterate = new ArrayList<>(this.coll);
        List<List<T>> lista2 = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < listIterate.size(); i++) {
            List<T> tmp = Arrays.asList(listIterate.get(i));
            lista2.add(tmp);
        }
        return computeCombinationsOriginal(lista2);
    }

    public static <T> List<List<T>> computeCombinationsOriginal(List<List<T>> lists) {
        List<List<T>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<T> list : lists) {
            List<List<T>> extraColumnCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T element : list) {
                if (combinations.isEmpty()) {
                    extraColumnCombinations.add(Arrays.asList(element));
                } else {
                    for (List<T> productList : combinations) {
                        List<T> newProductList = new ArrayList<>(productList);
                        newProductList.add(element);
                        extraColumnCombinations.add(newProductList);
                    }
                }
            }
            combinations = extraColumnCombinations;
        }
        return combinations;
    }

    public static <T> List<List<T>> appendElements(List<List<T>> combinations, List<T> extraElements) {
        return combinations.stream().flatMap(oldCombination
                        -> extraElements.stream().map(extra -> {
                    List<T> combinationWithExtra = new ArrayList<>(oldCombination);
                    combinationWithExtra.add(extra);
                    return combinationWithExtra;
                }))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private List<String> combineTwoLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s1 : list1) {
            for (String s2 : list2) {
                sb.setLength(0);
                sb.append(s1).append(' ').append(s2);
                result.add(sb.toString());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void forEachWithIndex(BiConsumer<T, Integer> bi) {
        listTMP = new ArrayList<>();
        listTMP.addAll(this.coll);

        for (int i = 0; i < listTMP.size(); i++) {
            bi.accept(listTMP.get(i), i);
        }
        this.coll = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Object set(int index, Object obj) {
        //System.out.println(index);
        list.add(index, (T) obj);
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object obj) {
        //list.remove(obj);
        // System.out.println("kasujemy " + obj);
        this.coll.remove(obj);
        listTMP.remove(obj);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class Combine {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for ( List<Object> li : combine( 
                Arrays.asList( "a", "b" ), 
                Arrays.asList( "X", "Y", "Z" ),
                Arrays.asList( 1, 2 ),
                Arrays.asList( "foo", "bar" ),
                Arrays.asList( true, false ) ) ) {
            System.out.println( li );
        }
    }

    public static List<List<Object>> combine( List<Object> l1, List<Object> l2, List<Object>... moreLists ) {

        List<List<Object>> cp = new ArrayList<>();

        for ( Object o1 : l1 ) {
            for ( Object o2 : l2 ) {
                List<Object> c = new ArrayList<>();
                c.add( o1 );
                c.add( o2 );
                cp.add( c );
            }
        }

        for ( List<Object> other : moreLists ) {
            
            List<List<Object>> newCp = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for ( List<Object> ocp : cp ) {
                for ( Object oo : other ) {
                    List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                    newList.addAll( ocp );
                    newList.add( oo );
                    newCp.add( newList );
                }
            }
            
            cp = newCp;
            
        }

        return cp;

    }

}
```